# How to show that the function $\log(1+\alpha t^2)$ is quasi convex?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, non-convex-optimization

I need to show that the function $f(t)=\log(1+\alpha t^2)$ is quasi convex. I checked its quasi convexity by plotting it using matlab as follows.
[image]

I really appreciate if you could please give me some directions to prove its quasi convexity.

Comment: I suppose that $\alpha>0$?

Comment: Yes, $\alpha $ is positive. @Bernard

Comment: Well,  then  it's obvious since $\ln(1+\alpha t^2)$ decreases on $\mathbf R^-$ (composition of a decreasing function by an increasing function) and increases on $\mathbf R^+$ ($1+\alpha t^2$ is increasing on this interval).

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, also the plot shows it but I need to find a prove for that for example using the following definition: for all $x,y \in R^n$ and $t \in [0,1]$, if $f(x) \le f(y)$ then $f(tx+(1-t)y) \le f(y)$.

Comment: Isn't it a well known result that a function is first which is first decreasing on an interval, then increasing on the remainder of the inerval of definition is quasi convex?

Comment: Yes of course. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Quasiconvexity of $f$ means that for all $a\in\mathbb R$, the set of all $t\in \mathbb R$ such that $f(t)\leq a$ is an interval. Can you compute that set ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to prove it using the definition: for all $x,y \in R^n$ and $t \in [0,1]$, if $f(x) \le f(y)$ then $f(tx+(1-t)y) \le f(y)$.